# Kindle USB-connection

Tags: usb, kindle

How does kindle distinguish pc connection and charging via grid? I'm trying to implement adapter and it needs kindle to be on when it's plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [USB Battery Charging specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/USB_Battery_Charging_1.2.pdf), specifically at section 3.